# javascript web workers multithreaded string search slower than single thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, web-worker

I have a fuzzysearch function. I have a list of 52k words. I'm running the function against each word. it takes about 30ms to finish.

i tried splitting it up into 8 web worker threads by sending 1/8th of the list to each worker (i have 8 threads on my cpu) using `myWorker.postMessage({targets:slice, search})`. but this is much slower, around 100ms.

my question is: **is it possible for multithreaded to be faster here? or is it simply too much data to copy around to finish in under 30ms threaded? is it possible to not copy the memory and have some kind of shared memory?**

(it seems like just simply sending the data to the workers is slower than me actually searching all the data in 1 thread!)

Comment: just a guess but maybe it's slower because the data you're processing is relatively small so the overhead of spinning up new workers is not worth it. would be interesting to see what the speeds are if you process 500k words

Comment: _"using `myWorker.postMessage({targets:slice, search})`"_ Why does code not transfer the object to the main thread?

Comment: @guest271314 ? that's giving 1/8th of the data (the slice) from the main thread to a worker

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar Yes, though the code at Question does not transfer the object created at `Worker` from `Worker` thread to main thread.

Comment: @FuzzyTree single takes 100ms. threaded takes 200ms. threaded seems to be consistently twice as slow with more data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to not copy the memory and have some kind of shared
>   memory?

You can use second parameter of `Worker.postMessage()` to [transfer](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#transferable-objects) the created object from `Worker` thread to main thread, or from main thread to worker.

```
// transfer data to `Worker` instance
worker.postMessage(data.buffer, [data.buffer]) // where `data` is an `ArrayBuffer`
```

```
// transfer data from `Worker` instance
self.postMessage(data.buffer, [data.buffer]) // where `data` is an `ArrayBuffer`
```

> **[Passing data by transferring ownership (transferable objects)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Passing_data_by_transferring_ownership_(transferable_objects))**
>
> Google Chrome 17+ and Firefox 18+ contain an additional way to pass
>   certain types of objects (transferable objects, that is objects
>   implementing the [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) interface) to or from a worker with
>   high performance. Transferable objects are transferred from one
>   context to another with a zero-copy operation, which results in a vast
>   performance improvement when sending large data sets.

Comment: sounds great. giveme a few minutes to test

Comment: looks like i need to use an arraybuffer. I'm not sure how to convert my array of strings into an arraybuffer

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar You can use `Blob` and `FileReader.protype.readAsArrayBuffer()` and `FileReader.prototype.readAsText()` or `TextEncoder()`, `TextDecoder()` and `Uint8Array()` to encode and decode text as a `TypedArray` where `.buffer` property : `ArrayBuffer` can be accessed  `var arr = ["abc", "bac", "cab"]; arr.forEach(function(s) {
  var encoder = new TextEncoder();
  var decoder = new TextDecoder();
  var encoded = encoder.encode(s);
  var decoded = decoder.decode(new Uint8Array(encoded.buffer));
  console.log(encoded, decoded)
})`

Comment: That code example works. `encoder.encode(slice.join(String.fromCharCode(0)))` This turns the whole array of strings into a buffer that can be transferred. BUT, the process of reformatting the data so it can be given to threads is still slower than just single threaded processing (it does seem slightly faster though)

Comment: You can try using `FileReaderSync` within `Worker`. Considered that creating a new instance of `TextEncoder` and `TextDecoder` would not meet requirement.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct even though it doesn't work in my case. WebWorkers are too much overhead for my specific example, but this answered the question!